# How to programatically send a TAB keystroke in netcf

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I need to have my edit box work the same for both tab and the enter key.

I have found lots of problems doing this in the application.  Is there some way that I can send a tab key to the form/edit box.

(Note that this has to be in the Compact Framework.)

---

**Solution:**
Here is what I ended up using:

```
// This class allows us to send a tab key when the the enter key is pressed for the mooseworks mask control.   
public class MaskKeyControl : MaskedEdit
{
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const Int32 VK_TAB = 0x09;

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_TAB, VK_TAB, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\r') 
            e.Handled = true;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

I am giving the answer to Hans because his code got me moving toward the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this control:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) {
            (this.Parent as ContainerControl).SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\r') e.Handled = true;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas that does not work.  Somehow the tab works, but the select next control does not.

I think it is because only the menus are enabled until tab is pressed and the control looses focus.

Very frustrating....

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can't tab to another control if none are enabled or visible.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started Hans.  See the solution that worked in the question.